# Google map and navigation within the mobile app

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing an application using Ionic framework and want to implement the google map & navigation feature within the application interface without using/redirecting it to Google Map application.
I am using type script/html/css/bootstrap language for developing the app. Please help me out to solve the problem. How to implement it within the app?

Thanks
Rajiv

Answer (score 0):

If you look the Google documentation of official page: https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/  then you'll find a example of code to use

Comment: Hi Grene,                                                                                           Thanks for the reply. But i want to implement app within the app like used in Uber app.